# Quantum mechanics, Dirac notation wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

How do I find $<x|p|\psi>$ in terms of $\psi (x) = <x|\psi>$

And again for $<x|H|\psi>$, where $H$ is the hamiltonian?

Comment: Hint: a complete set of states $\int dy \left | y \right > \left < y \right |$ can be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [completeness relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#The_unit_operator)
$$
\int dx \left|x\right> \left<x\right| = \mathbf{1}
$$
For example,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left<x| {\hat p} | \psi \right> &=& \left<x| {\hat p} \mathbf{1} |\psi \right> \\
&=& \int dy \left<x| {\hat p} |y\right> \left<y|\psi \right> \\
&=& \int dy \left<x| {\hat p} |y\right> \psi\left(y\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$